# Should I remove this plant that is growing on top of my milkweed?

Tags: plant-care

We have this milkweed that is usually covered in caterpillars this time of year, but hasn't really grown any leaves since this little plant popped up right in the middle of it.

[image: plant growing out of milkweed]

I'm afraid to rip it out in case it kills the milkweed. Do you think it is fine to leave it alone or should I try to get rid of it? And if I should get rid of it, how should I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have two plants growing in the same location and they will compete against each other for resources.  Since you want to keep the milkweed, it would be advisable to get rid of the other unwanted plant.  I would start with cutting the part of the unwanted plant that is above the ground. Hopefully, it don't grow again and that will prevent potential damage to the milkweed.  Beyond that, if the plant keeps growing you may have to take a risk of pulling out the unwanted plant from it's roots otherwise you may risk losing your milkweed as well.  Let us know the outcome.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your milkweed plant is [Asclepias curassavica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asclepias_curassavica). They are easy to start from seed or buy one in the garden center for $4. They grow quickly. Tear this old bare plant out and start over.

Answer (score 1):

Notes on weed cultivation: First off, congratulations on your milkweed being covered with caterpillars. I have had mine for at least 5 years now, and no caterpillars (well a few that happened to show up in Nov. a couple times, but they didn't survive Dec.)

I'm kind of surprised that the one plant is your only one, since I've got it now springing up all over the yard, what with the wind and all those million little parachute-seeds from each seed pod.

I did a little experiment with a milkweed plant yesterday. I dug it out by the root. A simple naked little scraggly sweet-potatoey looking knot with almost no root hairs or clinging dirt. Then I re-planted it a few feet away from where it came from, trying to see how hardy these weeds are. An hour later it was bent and wilty, its little leaves hanging limp off the stem. Well, no wonder, its root was sitting in dry dust, so I took pity & watered it(!) This morning it was perky and fresh, looking like nothing was bothering it. (not even the impending arrival of Monarchs). I think it's going to be just fine.

So I advise first trying JStorage's answer, and if that nasty old grass (or whatever it is) persists, don't fear destroying the delicate milkweed by digging up the whole clump, clearing out the interloper by the roots, & replanting the weed.

I hope those Monarchs appreciate it.